# Repair Disk that is not showing up in diskpart

Tags: partitioning, ssd, repair, diskpart

I have a new SSD NVME connected through USB. After a `dd` command (`sudo dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=/dev/sdb bs=32M conv=sync,noerror status=progress`) something went wrong.
Now I can't see it through windows diskpart, while I am still seeing it as a Volume E:.
What can I do in order to repair the disk? I don't care about the data in it.
I am posting here some screenshot related to my system (1tb ssd with windows, 1tb hardisk, 120gb usb drive, 1 external nvme ssd connected through usb):
[image][image][image][image]

Comment: By cloning the disc via dd you have also copied the ID generated by Windows and now Windows may have trouble to distinguish both drives. You can boot into Linux and overwrite the first few KB of the USB drive or use a Windows installation while the source disk is not connected.

Comment: @Robert The screes are from another windows computer, not the one that I cloned. It just seems that the drive is corrupted

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the disk from USB. Reboot the computer. Reconnect the disk.

If it appears and works as expected in diskpart, you're done.

If it doesn't, either the disk or USB adapter has failed and has to be replaced.

Comment: Reboot done and nothing changed. Isn't there something else that I can try? Both ssd and usb adapter are new...

Comment: @Ale1794 If they're new, then get them replaced. Even if you can get it to work now, you can't be sure that they won't fail again in a month or two, once you have some important data on that drive.